# Why raster stack function changes the number of layers

Tags: r, stack

I have a list of 12 rasters:

```
IN_folder_S2 <- "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC"
IN.files_S2 <- dir(IN_folder_S2, pattern= "_11.tif$",full.names = T)
IN.files_S2

IN.files_S2
 [1] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_ARVI_11.tif"  
 [2] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_GNDVI_11.tif" 
 [3] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_IRECI_11.tif" 
 [4] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_MSAVI2_11.tif"
 [5] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_MTCI_11.tif"  
 [6] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDI45_11.tif" 
 [7] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDVI_11.tif"  
 [8] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDWI_11.tif"  
 [9] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDWI2_11.tif" 
[10] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_bbb_30UXC_SAVI0_11.tif" 
[11] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_bbb_30UXC_SAVI1_11.tif" 
[12] "T:\\New_SM\\Indices_UXC/S2A2A_20191118_bbb_30UXC_SAVI2_11.tif"
```

After I stacked them:

```
INDEX_Nov19 <- stack(IN.files_S2)
```

the number of layers increased

```
   > names(INDEX_Nov19)
 [1] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_ARVI_11"    "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_GNDVI_11.1"
 [3] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_GNDVI_11.2" "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_IRECI_11.1"
 [5] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_IRECI_11.2" "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_MSAVI2_11" 
 [7] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_MTCI_11.1"  "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_MTCI_11.2" 
 [9] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDI45_11.1" "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDI45_11.2"
[11] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDVI_11"    "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDWI_11"   
[13] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_NDWI2_11"   "S2A2A_20191118_bbb_30UXC_SAVI0_11"  
[15] "S2A2A_20191118_bbb_30UXC_SAVI1_11"   "S2A2A_20191118_bbb_30UXC_SAVI2_11"
```

I have applied the same method for other files and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your files have more than one layer themselves, so they contribute more than one layer to the final stack. R gives them names with `.1` and `.2` and so on. eg GNDVI and IRECI but not ARVI:

```
 [1] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_ARVI_11"    "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_GNDVI_11.1"
 [3] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_GNDVI_11.2" "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_IRECI_11.1"
 [5] "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_IRECI_11.2" "S2A2A_20191118_137_30UXC_MSAVI2_11"
```

Comment: I see, thank you so much!